# Regex Match Hexidecimal in Groups of 2-8

Tags: regex, hex, binary-search

I am working on a regular expression to match against a hexadecimal string and having some trouble near the end. I am specifically looking for groups of 2 bytes that do not contain 00 that are between 2 and 8 bytes long. I have it all working except that when there are less than 8 bytes, it will allow extra 00 to be in it sometimes.

https://regex101.com/r/jq3QpP/1/

```
(?!(00)+)([0-9a-fA-F]{2,8})?(?!(00)+)    // This on the below text gives the following matches


C86B0200554E0200C86B02000000000000000000270000008109000000000000EC6A050079750
18881000000410000280100000000000000000001000002010400000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000F65FA45900000000FF0000002F0000000000000049000000403C9F5
A000000000000000000000000FFFF330000000000000F06EAE8333536

Match 1
Full match  0-8 `C86B0200`
Group 2.    0-8 `C86B0200`
Match 2
Full match  8-16    `554E0200`
Group 2.    8-16    `554E0200`
Match 3
Full match  16-21   `C86B0`
Group 2.    16-21   `C86B0`
Match 4
Full match  21-21   ``
Match 5
Full match  39-47   `02700000`
Group 2.    39-47   `02700000`
```

In match 1,2,5 there are extra 00, in match 3, it missed the 20 for some reason. If you have an idea what I missed, please let me know

Comment: Does the `00` need to align with a byte, or can it be anywhere. ie should `10011111` not match?

Comment: It needs to align with a byte, I also tried ([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]){1,4} but I had problems there too

Comment: The data is header info from a file which contains INT32 numbers I need to extract, but the numbers are separated by multiple 00 if that helps understand what I am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid matching `00` by allowing only one `0` in two digits at a time instead:

```
(?:[A-F1-9][A-F0-9]|[A-F0-9][A-F1-9]){1,4}(?=(?:..)*$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2hebvf/2

Comment: Thanks, that was a great idea. I got an error on your fiddle, but using that idea this worked: `(?:[A-F1-9][A-F0-9]|[A-F0-9][A-F1-9]){1,4}`

Comment: Oops, my solution doesn't keep it byte aligned

Comment: This one seems to be working `(([A-F1-9][A-F0-9]|[A-F0-9][A-F1-9]){1,4})(?:00)+`

Comment: I was using a variable-width lookbehind assertion, which is not supported by some tools and programming languages, to ensure byte-alignment to the start of the string, which is what could be causing errors in your tool, but if your string always has a even number of digits, then simply ensuring an even number of digits till the end of the string is enough. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: By the way your proposed regex with `(?:00)+` in the end would not work if the string ends with `000A`, for example. You should use a lookahead assertion that matches an even number of digits until the end of the string instead. Feel free to accept this answer if you do find it to be correct.